# How to sum multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have database that has 12 columns of numeric data - one column for each month.

Column names are

```
Jan, Feb, Mar. Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov and Dec.
```

I know how to write code to sum first 3 months (Jan, Feb, and Mar) and return value in Total.

```
SELECT Jan+Feb+Mar AS Total FROM MyData
```

Question: How do I write generic query to give me sum of first N months?

Do I need to write code to generate the SQL statement or is there another way?

Comment: I think you need to write code to generate the SQL, because SQL logic can't decide which columns are included in the query.  A better design might be to spread your months across _rows_.  Then, you could restrict to the time frame you want using a simple `WHERE` clause, without having to resort to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Any chance you can change your design?  If you had this in two columns `(month, value)` and 12 rows, it would be trivial.  Having these types of issues is a symptom of a design that's not a SQL Pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need dynamic SQL to auto generate a query with the first N months.  But you could also define a view which contains all the sums, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW sums AS (
    SELECT Jan AS total1,
    SELECT Jan + Feb AS total2,
    SELECT Jan + Feb + Mar AS total3,
    ...
    SELECT Jan + Feb + Mar + ... + Nov + Dec AS total12
    FROM yourTable
)
```

Then, you could query the view and access any sum you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a string which you can execute using [`sp_executesql` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @query = 'SELECT #selectColumns# FROM tableName'

--- write your logic to get how many columns you need based on value of `N`
--- make their summation  as stringToReplace (i.e. = 'Jan + Feb + Mar ...')
--- and replace them with #selectColumns# in @query

EXECUTE(@query)
```

PS: if you are using database other than MSSQL Server, you should be able to find some way to execute string as SQL command.

For example, for MySQL, there is `prepare`

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

For Oracle, you'll be having [`EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query;`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_13dyn.htm)

Comment: How do you know which database the OP is using?

Comment: As it's not mentioned by OP, I assume that's not what he is asking. I think the main question he is having is how to ask sql server which columns to select

Comment: Again, how do you know the OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: oh.. ok...  you're right.. your approach to create a view makes more sense... +1 for that!

Answer (score 0):

If, you are working with *SQL Server*, then you could use `APPLY` operator to generate the month sequence.

```
SELECT
       SUM(a.Total) Totals 
FROM table t
CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (1, 'Jan', Jan), (2, 'Feb', Feb), (3, 'Mar', Mar),
               ....
               (12, 'Dec', Dec)
)a(Seq, Months, Total)
WHERE a.Seq <= 3 -- pass Nos of Months to get the sum of Totals
```